# What caused TargetUpdated to be triggered?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertychanged

In an event handler for `TargetUpdated` on a `TextBox` I would like to know what property was raised to trigger the target to be updated.

Explained with code, I have a `TextBox` in my XAML (note the binding):

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding MySubViewModel.MyValue}" />
```

On this `TextBox`, I'm subscribing to `TargetUpdated`:

```
myTextBox.TargetUpdated += OnTargetUpdated;
```

And here is my event handler:

```
private void OnTargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    // Am I here because of PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySubViewModel")
    // or because of PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyValue") ?
}
```

As the comment states, in my event handler I would like to know what triggered the event to be raised. Is it possible?

*That is*, was it because of this:

```
MySubViewModel = new SubViewModel { MyValue = "Muppet" };
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySubViewModel"));
```

...or because of this:

```
MyValue = "Muppet";
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyValue"));
```

Comment: In `OnTargetUpdated` handler you will get Target DP (Text in this case) which is updated and not the source property which cause the update in target because you can manually update the target w/o any source property changed as well. Moreover, code relying on it doesn't make sense too.

Comment: Ok. So I guess what you are saying is that it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah to best of my knowledge, framework doesn't support anything like that in built.

Comment: I used `?new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString();` where event is called, to get some Raw caller informations. Dependent of your structure in can give a hint of the caller.